# Is there a way to add hooks to a Thor class in order to run code before/after all commands?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, hook, thor

I'm working on a CLI tool powered by [the Thor gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/thor). Say I have a `Cli` class that inherits from `Thor`, which defines a CLI tool that has a few commands associated with it:

```rb
class Cli < Thor
  def version
    # Prints out the version
  end

  def something
    # Does something else
  end

  def thing
    # Does a different thing
  end
end
```

**How can I define a method that runs before all commands, or after all commands?**

For example, say I create a couple private methods – let's call them `setup` and `teardown`. How can I make `setup` run before `version`, `something`, and `thing`? And how can I make `teardown` run after `version`, `something`, and `thing`?

I am hoping there is some sort of way to declare a hook method (similar to Rails' `before_action`) so I can avoid manually calling `setup` first in every command, and `teardown` last in every command.

Comment: There is nothing built in but there is a gem called [thor-hollaback](https://github.com/kddeisz/thor-hollaback) which implements callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no built-in way of doing such callbacks in the Thor gem. (I'd think this would be a popular feature, but maybe I'm looking at things the wrong way.)

An above comment points to a third-party solution, [thor-hollaback](https://github.com/kddeisz/thor-hollaback), but I have not tried it.